# Filtered lookup field

Tags: lookup-column

I would like to apply filtering to existing out-of-the-box lookup fields (without InfoPath).

The solution should be limited to GUI only: when Backup/Restoring to a clean farm the filtering would be gone but all the data preserved and usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the jQuery library for SharePoint, [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com).  There is one operation, [SPFilterDropdown](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPFilterDropdown), that allows you to filter a lookup column via CAML.  Usage example from the documentation:

```
$().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown({
  relationshipList: "Countries",
  relationshipListColumn: "Title",
  columnName: "Country",
  CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Active' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>",
  completefunc: null,
  debug: false
});
```

I haven't used this particular operation, but the other aspects of the library are stellar.

Comment: Seems good. I will get back to this after checking the solution out.

Comment: Tried and this works with single choice columns (not multicolumns). This is fine and problem solved.

Comment: Just wrap the call in $(document).ready(function() { $().SPServices...